# Where are the git log files? ie error log, output log etc

Tags: git, intellij-idea

When opening the commit window in intellij, intellij calls some git command and gets stuck saying "Performing VCS Refresh...". In order to debug the problem I'd like to see the git log. Searching on google for terms like "git log" clearly points to the wrong thing.

Any ideas where the git error log is located?

Answer (score 5):

`git` doesn't log anything: It reports all messages to `stdout` and `stderr`. If there are any specific logs about what's going on, they'd probably be in the `IntelliJ Event Log`. That being said, have you tried running a `git fetch --all` or anything similar manually? Getting `IntelliJ` out of the way might make the underlying issue clearer.